# Shading does not work with patches specifying face colors?

Tags: matlab, mesh

I don't understand why the following code throws a warning:

```
% mesh of a plane at z=0 for x,y in [0,5] with 20 vertices per side
n = 20;
[x,y] = ndgrid( linspace(0,5,n) );
x = x(:); y = y(:); z = zeros(n^2,1);

% triangulation to obtain faces, and draw a patch with random color for each face
F = delaunay(x,y);
V = [x,y,z];
patch( 'Vertices', V, 'Faces', F, 'FaceVertexCData', rand( size(F,1), 1 ) );
axis tight; grid on; box off;

% faceted shading works fine, but interp doesn't seem to work
shading('faceted'); % works fine
shading('interp'); % throws a warning

   Warning: Error creating or updating Patch
    Error in value of property  FaceVertexCData
    Number of colors must equal number of vertices
```

Hopefully the comments are enough explanation to understand the issue -- but briefly, it seems that interpolation of face color does not work when the property `FaceVertexCData` specifies the colors of faces and not vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, if you want to convert a vector of colors for each face to a vector of colors for each vertex, you can use the following function:

```
function cdata = face2vertex(cdata,faces,nvert)

    fmax = max(faces(:));
    if nargin < 3, nvert=fmax; end
    if size(faces,1)~=3, faces=faces'; end

    assert( size(faces,1)==3, 'Bad faces size.' );
    assert( size(faces,2)==numel(cdata), 'Input size mismatch.' );
    assert( nvert >= fmax, 'Number of vertices too small.' );

    faces = faces(:);
    cdata = repelem( cdata(:), 3 ); % triplicate face colors

    nfpv  = accumarray( faces, 1, [nvert,1] ); % #of faces per vertex
    cdata = accumarray( faces, cdata, [nvert,1] ) ./ max(1,nfpv);

end
```

This function takes in input:

- a `Nfaces x 1` column vector of colors `cdata`,
- a `Nfaces x 3` array of vertex indices (one triangle per row),
- optionally the number of vertices, which will override the size of the output (otherwise inferred from face indices).

and returns a `Nvertices x 1` column vector of colors such that for each vertex, the color is averaged across the faces that contain it.

Answer (score 2):

As the warning message states, if you want to use the `'interp'` shading method, you need to have your `FaceVertexCData` have an entry for each *vertex*. Currently, you have an entry for each face.

```
patch( 'Vertices', V, 'Faces', F, 'FaceVertexCData', rand( size(V,1), 1 ) );
shading('interp')
```

This is not an issue or a bug, because `shading` sets the [`FaceColor` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html#property_FaceColor) of the patch object to `'interp'` which explicitly requires that there be an entry in `FaceVertexCData` for each vertex.

> `'interp'` — Interpolate the color across each face. First, specify `CData` or `FaceVertexCData` as an array **containing one value per vertex**. Determine the face colors by using a bilinear interpolation of the values at each vertex.

Comment: Your answer makes me smile because this is exactly what the warning says; I can read, but I don't understand why that is the case? It is "legal" (according to the documentation) to specify `FaceVertexCData` for each face, and the documentation for `shading` does not mention any particular issue with the option `interp`. Do you think this is a bug and if not, why would there be no mention about this issue in the documentation?

Comment: Please don't take it personally, and let me know if my question is unclear (I added some text under the excerpt), but I will downvote your answer because I don't think it is useful.

Comment: @Sheljohn It is not a bug. I've included links to the official documentation and added an excerpt which explicitly defines the behavior

Comment: I will select my answer in two days because it allowed me to circumvent this limitation, but thank you for your answer!